# Android. Making my object appear anywhere on the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

If I want a bunch of objects that appear let's say middle, middle right and occupy have the ability to occupy any part of the screen, would I use gridlayout or relative layout and dp to customize the location?

I think I explained it badly. If I used an analogy, it would be like whack a mole with the hole screen. I was thinking of making a large amount of rows and columns in gridlayout or just using dp. Any insight or suggestions?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: I think I'll just directly draw pixels using canvas or use something like absolute layout for maximum control. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about gridview is that its entire purpose is scrolling.  If you have lots of data and want to scroll through it in a grid, that's the right answer.  If you have a fixed amount of data you want to display in a grid, you want something else-  a TableLayout likely.